# Preview Angular-ui bootstrap gh-pages branch on windows localhost

Tags: git, bash, jekyll, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to run the project page on my localhost windows server 2008 R2 machine on the Git Bash prompt.

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages
```

I tried to add _config.yml with content below:

```
baseurl:          /bootstrap
```

And run "jkeyll serve" command

```
User@Server ~/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap (gh-pages)
$ jekyll serve --baseurl ''
Configuration file: c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap/_config.yml
            Source: c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap
       Destination: c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap/_site
      Generating...
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-boot
strap/bootstrap/_site/node_modules/grunt-html2js/node_modules/jade/node_modules/monocle/node_modules/readdirp/examples/n
ode_modules/event-stream/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/example
```

Then, I found that the example folder in above */wordwrap folder is not available from the error above, but upon putting a folder there and re-running the command

```
User@Server ~/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap (gh-pages)
$ jekyll serve --baseurl ''
Configuration file: c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap/_config.yml
            Source: c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap
       Destination: c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-bootstrap/bootstrap/_site
      Generating...
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - c:/Users/User/My Documents/gitHub/angular-boots
trap/bootstrap/_site/node_modules/grunt-html2js/node_modules/jade/node_modules/monocle/node_modules/readdirp/examples/no
de_modules/event-stream/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/example/center.js
```

BTW, I'm referring to below site to try to get gh-pages branch working on localhost (I used step 1. and 4, but cant figure out step 2 and 3, thought might not applicable to this project, but I might be wrong...)

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

Please let me know if someone manage to get it on the Windows localhost. Thanks!